# R keep double quotes from list to String

Tags: r, tostring

I have a list that looks like this

```
[1] "SCOPUS_ID:84942789431" "SCOPUS_ID:84928151617" "SCOPUS_ID:84939229259" "SCOPUS_ID:84946407175"
[5] "SCOPUS_ID:84933039513" "SCOPUS_ID:84942789431" "SCOPUS_ID:84942607254" "SCOPUS_ID:84948165954"
[9] "SCOPUS_ID:84926379258" "SCOPUS_ID:84946771354" "SCOPUS_ID:84944223683" "SCOPUS_ID:84942789431"
[13] "SCOPUS_ID:84939169499" "SCOPUS_ID:84947104346" "SCOPUS_ID:84948764343" "SCOPUS_ID:84938075139"
[17] "SCOPUS_ID:84946196118" "SCOPUS_ID:84930820238" "SCOPUS_ID:84947785321" "SCOPUS_ID:84933496680"
[21] "SCOPUS_ID:84942789431"
```

I want to use the function toString but to keep the double quotes so to look like this

```
[1] " \"SCOPUS_ID:84942789431\", \"SCOPUS_ID:84928151617\", ... "
```

Comment: What is the current `class` of the elements in your vector? I'm assuming they're already strings, so I don't understand why you'd want to use `as.character` on them. However, if you want to wrap them in quotes, just use the `paste` function.

Comment: I don't want to use paste because I have a huge list and will take 2-3 seconds to create that string

Comment: If I use paste it will look like this *[1] "SCOPUS_ID:84942789431," "SCOPUS_ID:84928151617," "SCOPUS_ID:84939229259,"* How can I place the comma between the double quotes?

Comment: The `class()` says "array"? Do you have a two dimensional object? What does `dim()` return? If it's just a vector, you can use `shQuote` to add in the quote and `paste()` to collapse: `paste(shQuote(a), collapse=", ")`

Comment: dim() returns 7, but it depends because I use mongoDB and I get around 250 documents, each with different output; but the solution with paste() was enough to get what I want and is efficient also; thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll admit that I'm fairly confused by what you're asking for, but I think this is what you want:

```
x <- c("SCOPUS_ID:84942789431", "SCOPUS_ID:84928151617", "SCOPUS_ID:84939229259")
paste('"', x, '"', sep = "", collapse = ", ")
# [1] "\"SCOPUS_ID:84942789431\", \"SCOPUS_ID:84928151617\", \"SCOPUS_ID:84939229259\""
```

I know you said you didn't want to use `paste` because it'll take 2-3 seconds, but I can't think of an alternative that gives you what you want right now. I'm sure others will have suggestions.

Comment: I forgot it executed the program very slowly with paste when i had to iterate through all the list to get this IDs, but I changed the structure of the list and with your solution it works instantly, thank you very much :)